# Thumbnail preview not showing in Video Embed Field Module

Tags: files

I am using Video Embed Field Module for embeding videos in dupal 7 site. The thumbnail preview is not showing. I created a view block in the preview section of the view its shows the thumbnail but when the block in in some region of page it only displays the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the access permissions for your thumbnail images

Comment: how to check this?

Comment: If you are using linux server and you have control of command terminal, then do the following. Go to the folder where the thumbnails are present and Type the command `ls -l` and see the result.

Comment: This command just list the images. nothing else

Comment: You can  also confirm the permission issue by inspecting the page with inspect element.That will show error if the image request had some issue.Or else you can ( for temporary purpose and only in development server) , change the folder/file permission to all  using command ` sudo chmod -R 777 files `.

Comment: Thanks for your help problem solved. It was a css class in my theme which sets the img display to none.

Comment: @Fawad Your Welcome.It is always a good practice to do inspect element  follow specially in these kind of sitiations